# Where does Picasa 3 store video captions

Tags: picasa

I'm migrating my photos and videos stored in Picasa 3.8 from a PC to a Mac.  I have all of my data migrated over and just about everything looks correct.  However, I just noticed that none of the captions for my videos made it across.  Does anyone know where specifically Picasa 3 stores the caption metadata for video files?  The only trace I've found of the video captions is in Picasa's synclog directory, but the name of that directory makes me think it's some byproduct of the sync operation, not the actual repository of caption data.